# Oldest books on Calculus

Tags: calculus, reference-request, math-history

What are some of the oldest books available on Calculus? I'm curious to see how the old teaching and explanatory styles compare to modern ones.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You mean like Newton's "[Method of Fluxions](http://www.archive.org/details/methodoffluxions00newt)"?

Or perhaps de l'Hospital's ["Analyse des infiniment petits"](http://www.archive.org/details/infinimentpetits1716lhos00uoft)?

Comment: Precisely. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: @SubtleArray, oh did you meant *that* old?

Comment: while I upvoted this, it is not fair to compare "explanatory style" in Newton's fluxions to any modern calculus book. For one thing, the standard for rigour evolved quite a bit in the past 300 years.

Comment: Apologies for my bad grammar. I more or less meant "how the ideas were outlined." I wanted to compare the differences between how Calculus was originally _explained_ to how it's explained today.

Answer (score 3):

[Wikipedia lists these important publications in calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_important_publications_in_mathematics#Calculus)

Edit: Related is this [link](http://www.gap-system.org/~history/HistTopics/References/The_rise_of_calculus.html) that has a reference on history of calculus

Comment: I just spent the last 20 minutes combing through Wikipedia and hadn't ran into that link once. Great find, and list. Thank you.

Comment: @SubtleArray Please note I have added another link you may find useful which includes C.B.Boyer's book

Answer (score 2):

The wiki article doesn't seem to mention Isaac Barrow's *Lectiones Geometricae* (1669); which Morris Kline says is "one of the great contributions to the calculus". This should be a good example of how the old thinking differs, as it uses geometrical arguments rather than analytical.

Comment: http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k1095218